# Scala - Count number of adjacent repeated chars in String

Tags: scala, count, functional-programming, immutability

I have this function that counts the number of adjacent repeated chars inside a String.

```
def adjacentCount( s: String ) : Int = {
    var cont = 0
    for (a <- s.sliding(2)) {
        if (a(0) == a(1)) cont = cont + 1
    }
        cont
    }
}
```

But I'm supposed to create a function that does exactly the same, but using only immutable variables or loop instructions, in a "purely" functional way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use the `count` method on the *Iterator*:

```
val s = "aabcddd"

s.sliding(2).count(p => p(0) == p(1))
// res1: Int = 3
```